# Adding next button in custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, customization

I have a custom list `EditText`. When I clicked the `EditText`,  the custom keyboard shows up. I would like to add next button in custom keyboard.

Upon clicking that next button, the next `EditText` field should have focus.

How can I implement next button in custom keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

If you create the layout through xml, set the id of nextFocus view in this attribute

```
  android:nextFocusForward="id_of_the_next_focus_view"
```

For setting next button in ime use this attribute

```
  android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

This will do the job for you.

Comment: I am asking how to add the next button. In my custom keyboard next and done buttons are not there. So, i want to add next button.

Comment: I customize the keyboard itself. I am not using android default keyboard. I using customized keyboard. In that all the buttons are created. In that i did not knowing how to add next button with action.

Answer (score 1):

In `onStartInput()` you can handle the IME options. Here you can change the keyboard layout with one which contains a "Next" key or something similar.

When the Next key (you have to check the keycode) was pressed, you have to make sure that any typed text was commited [1] to editor and afterwards call `getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);`

Hope this will help.

[1]

```
if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
   getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(mComposing, 1);
   mComposing.setLength(0);
}
```